# Laravel 5.2 LAMP Stack POST route error 404

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, lamp, ampps

I am using Laravel 5.2 on bitnami LAMP. I also tried the same in the AMPPS. OS is Ubuntu 16.

All the GET routes are perfectly working. But whenever I hit a post route (even through ajax), I get the following error :

> Not Found - 404 The requested URL was not found on this server.

By the way, I read other solutions online

I have enabled :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

In the apache httpd configs I have set:

```
AllowOverride All
```

my .htaccess which is in the project/public folder is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

PS : This code perfectly works on windows XAMP server. I cant get this to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you also show your virtual host?

Comment: TheFallen, Im not running a virtual host

Comment: That's probably why it's not working. Make a virtual host an try the post routes again.

Comment: TheFallen, can you link me for a guide to setting up this virtual host please?

Comment: Check this http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/ step 5 and 6. You can also run `php artisan serve` from the project folder which will boot a webserver at http://localhost:8000/, instead of making a virtual host.

Comment: TheFallen, Im using LAMP, And I cannot create virtual host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116432/discussion-between-geeth-w-and-thefallen).